# Tanh activation function giving higher error and worse output than sigmoid one

Tags: backpropagation, neural-network

I implemented the `tanh` function as my activation function, but the result somehow is worse than with a sigmoid activation function. Moreover, while checking the error, it shows that the error goes up down and up again, over and over.

Here are example of error using `tanh`:

```
epoch:1823
current error:0.1383121756710299

epoch:1824
current error:0.13831547638188654

epoch:1825
current error:0.13831887880040633

epoch:1826
current error:0.13832238240031222

epoch:1827
current error:0.13832598673034413

epoch:1828
current error:0.1383296914155071

epoch:1829
current error:0.13833349615821078

epoch:1830
current error:0.13833740073931955

epoch:1831
current error:0.1383414050191362

epoch:1832
current error:0.13834550893832906

epoch:1833
current error:0.1383497125188264

epoch:1834
current error:0.13835401586468998

epoch:1835
current error:0.1383584191629793

epoch:1836
current error:0.13836292268462677

epoch:1837
current error:0.1383675267853283

epoch:1838
current error:0.13837223190646183

epoch:1839
current error:0.13837703857605013

epoch:1840
current error:0.138381947409767

epoch:1841
current error:0.1383869591120036

epoch:1842
current error:0.13839207447699467

epoch:1843
current error:0.13839729439001985

epoch:1844
current error:0.1384026198286766

epoch:1845
current error:0.1384080518642369
```

Meanwhile, sigmoid activation function does not show this. Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please show your implementation of `tanh`? If this is the only difference to the working case, then you may have done something wrong there.

Comment: I implemented it using java, here is my formula for tanh 

activation function: 
SumNodeWeight=Math.exp(SumNodeWeight*2)-1)/(Math.exp(SumNodeWeight*2)+1);
Derivative activation function:

partialDerivative=1-(activationValue*activationValue);


FYI: when I use this for small dataset the error still decrease but when I use this for big dataset the error decrease and increase

Comment: Is `SumNodeWeight=` supposed to be `activationValue=`?

Comment: yup, it is activation value well it same as
activationValue=Math.exp(SumNodeWeight*2)-1)/(Math.exp(SumNodeWeight*2)+1);